# Rails forms - When no checkboxes are checked, param is not included in POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, rest, activerecord, post

I have a Task model, which is joined in a many-to-many relationship with an Objective model.

I have a Task edit form where a user can associate any Objective with a Task via checkboxes. When a checkbox is checked, it should indicate an association between the Task and a particular Objective; when a checkbox is not checked, there should be no association. This should be persisted to the database when the form submits.

```
<%= form_for @task do |f| %>
  <% Objective.all.each do |objective| %>
    <%= check_box_tag :objective_ids, objective.id, @task.objectives.include?(objective), :name => 'task[objective_ids][]' %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Updating a Task seems to work absolutely fine *as long as one checkbox is checked by the user*, but when  the user does not check any checkboxes, the `:objective_ids` param (which is an array of Objective ids) is not included in the POST action at all. Because of this, when I do `@task.update_attributes(params[:task])` in the controller, the Task's collection of Objectives is not updated (i.e. the Task should no longer have any Objectives associated with it, because no checkboxes were checked).

So how can I ensure the `:objective_ids` param is included in the POST, even if only as an empty array?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Add hidden field above all checkboxes with empty value. It will be sent in case user didn't check any checkboxes.

```
<%= form_for @task do |f| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag "task[objective_ids][]", nil %>
  <% Objective.all.each do |objective| %>
    <%= check_box_tag :objective_ids, objective.id, @task.objectives.include?(objective), :name => 'task[objective_ids][]' %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Here is a good [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes-revised) about this.
You may also want to check the [source code](https://github.com/railscasts/017-habtm-checkboxes-revised) for it.

Comment: @Jignesh, it's in my answer ;)

Comment: FWIW, the railscast link in the answer requires a subscription to see the info, while the asciicast link in the comments is freely visible.

Comment: this does not work as a general solution, if the list of checkboxes has one with value 0, adding the "nil" checkbox would select it